# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'id'), channel fetching error

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js, bots, typeerror

I need help with this error. This command deletes ALL the messages sent by the specified user in the channel the command was ran in. Whenever I run the command, the console tells me that 'id' is not defined. How do I fix this, please?

```
const { SlashCommandBuilder } = require('@discordjs/builders');
const {
  EmbedBuilder,
  PermissionsBitField,
  ButtonBuilder,
  ActionRowBuilder,
  ButtonStyle,
  ChannelType,
} = require('discord.js');

module.exports = {
  data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
    .setName('clearuser')
    .setDescription('Deletes all messages from a specific user in the server.')
    .addUserOption((option) =>
      option
        .setName('user')
        .setDescription('The user whose messages to delete.')
        .setRequired(true)
    ),
  async execute(interaction) {
    if (
      !interaction.member.permissions.has(
        PermissionsBitField.Flags.ManageMessages
      )
    )
      return await interaction.reply({
        content: "You don't have the permissions to execute this command.",
        ephemeral: true,
      });

    const { options, guild, author } = interaction;
    const targetUser = interaction.options.getUser('user');

    if (!targetUser)
      return await interaction.reply({
        content: 'Please specify a valid user.',
        ephemeral: true,
      });

    // Fetch messages from all channels in the server
    const messages = await interaction.guild.channels.cache
      .filter((channel) => channel.type === ChannelType.GuildText)
      .map(async (channel) => {
        return await channel.messages.fetch({ limit: 100 });
      });

    const allMessages = (await Promise.all(messages)).flat();
    const targetUserMessages = allMessages.filter(
      (msg) => msg.author.id === targetUser.id
    );

    // Delete messages from all channels
    await Promise.all(
      targetUserMessages.map(async (msg) => {
        try {
          await msg.delete();
        } catch (error) {
          console.error(`Error deleting message: ${error.message}`);
        }
      })
    );

    const embed = new EmbedBuilder()
      .setColor('DarkRed')
      .setDescription(
        `:white_check_mark: Deleted ${targetUserMessages.length} messages from ${targetUser}.`
      );

    const button = new ActionRowBuilder().addComponents(
      new ButtonBuilder()
        .setCustomId('clearuser')
        .setEmoji('️')
        .setStyle(ButtonStyle.Danger)
    );

    const replyMessage = await interaction.reply({
      embeds: [embed],
      components: [button],
    });

    const collector = replyMessage.createMessageComponentCollector();

    collector.on('collect', async (i) => {
      if (i.customId === 'clearuser') {
        if (!i.member.permissions.has(PermissionsBitField.Flags.ManageMessages))
          return;

        interaction.deleteReply();
      }
    });
  },
};
```

I figured it's not getting the messages from the channel, so I added the ChannelType requirement, but it still did not work.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Either of `msg.author` or `targetUser` is undefined. Please console.log them and update your code. Also, use [`bulkDelete()`](https://old.discordjs.dev/#/docs/discord.js/main/class/TextChannel?scrollTo=bulkDelete) rather than deleting messages individually.